# Excel Top 5 Formula Explanation

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

This formula below works wonderfully!

But I am having some trouble wrapping my head around what is going on.

Can somebody explain what is happening here step by step.

I have a good knowledge of formulae and VBA, I have a basic knowledge of array formulae but this has puzzled me.

Evaluating the formula in excel really didn't help.

`=INDEX($B$2:$B$11,MATCH(1,INDEX(($B$2:$B$11=LARGE($B$2:$B$11,ROWS(F$1:F1)))*(COUNTIF(F$1:F1,$A$2:$A$11)=0),),0))`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As generally with formulas start  inside:

- `ROWS(F$1:F1)` is same as `ROW()-1`, so it's simply the rank
- `LARGE($B$2:$B$11,ROWS(..))` returns the score of actual rank.
  *this formula is composed to work using the same formula in both columns. You could leave only this in second column for the same result*
- `$B$2:$B$11=LARGE(...)` results an array with `true` where score in column B equals the actual one
- `COUNTIF(F$1:F1,$A$2:$A$11)=0`.
  This doesn't make sense in this column, just an array of `true`.
  In column E, however, first parameter will be `E$1:E1`, yielding `0` for all rows where name isn't yet listed in column E. `=0` converts it to a list of `true` for values not yet listed   and `false` for names already listed.
- `INDEX((..)*(),)` calculates intersect of previous two arrays (score as required by actual rank AND name not yet listed), resulting an array
- `MATCH(1,INDEX(..),0)` returns the index of first item fulfilling criteria
- `INDEX($B$2:$B$B11,MATCH(..))` returns the next name / score

Comment: Juh That is exactly what i was looking for thank you very much